# Create a java file with directory

Tags: java, file

I am trying to create a file (`/data/test/userid/feedid/test.flv`)

If that directory does not exist, I get this exception:

```
java.io.FileNotFoundException
```

Is there any good way to solve this problem?

I have found commons.io, but there isn't any function that can solve this.

Comment: In Java API you have File.mkdirs() which will help you. Which will create all necessary directories.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[`File#mkdirs`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#mkdirs%28%29) will create the paths structure denoted by this `File`.  For example

```
File file = new File("/data/test/userid/feedid/test.flv");
File parent = file.getParentFile();
if (parent.exists() || parent.mkdirs()) {
   //...
} else {
    throw new IOException("Failed to create output directory " + parent);
}
```

Comment: That makes a nice change ;)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this must work:

```
File file = new File("data//test//userid//feedid//test.flv");
file.getParentFile().mkdirs();
FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

Comment: Don't need the "//", single "/" are fine ... +1 otherwise

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
String fileLocation= //your location to store;
File fileDir=new File(fileLocation);
if(!fileDir.exists())
{
    fileDir.getParentFile().mkdirs(); // to create directory if not exists

}
```

Comment: What happens if the `mkdirs` call fails?  Do you have to do another `fileDir.exists()` to check for it?  Seems like a waste of effort to me.  Right idea though

Comment: What do you mean if it fails? I don't get you.

Comment: `mkdirs` can fail - From the docs *"Note that if this operation fails it may have succeeded in creating some of the necessary parent directories"*

Comment: Oh. I used this code, so I copied here and it was working fine for me. So what is the best option to create directory then?

Comment: The code is fine, but now you need to do another check to see if it worked.  Try using something more like `if (fileDir.exists() || fileDir.mkdirs()) {...}` assuming that `fileDir` is the path you want to create..

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you need to do first:

```
File dir = new File("/data/test/userid/feedid");
if (!dir.exists()){ 
     dir.mkdir();
}
```